# Will my PHP and JavaScript code for selling digital goods still work after Nov 20th?

Tags: php, javascript, android-pay, jwt

I am using Google Payment Processing Services for multiple apps, and I am confused as to which I will be able to continue using.

With one account I use for a web app (which sells credits for services on a website), I signed up for Google Wallet for digital goods. I did not receive an email about the deadline on that email address. The only red notices I receive are about taxes and setting up an account when I log in to the account at http://wallet.google.com/merchant.

Therefore I believe I will still be able to use this service and won't need a separate merchant (it says "Attractive pricing: the most favorable of 5% or 1.9% + 30c (USD) per transaction is automatically applied." on the page where I can sign up)

Now what I wonder is if my PHP and JavaScript code will still work? I can't find the tutorial I used to create the code any more; instead, everything is in Python. No mention of PHP. That makes me wonder if it's still going to process everything okay. Right now when clicking on it everything is branded with Google Wallet and such…

Here's how my site works:

- I include `<script src="https://wallet.google.com/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>` *(This actually makes me think that I should be all set…)*
- I have a success and failure handler function in **JavaScript**.
- I have a **seller secret and a seller identifier**.
- With those I use **jwt** to create jwt tokens for each digital good and its price.
- I hand that token to its respective **JavaScript**.

```
function purchase_digitalgood() {
  google.payments.inapp.buy({
    'jwt'     : generatedJwt_forthisdigitalgood,
    'success' : successHandler,
    'failure' : failureHandler
  });
}
```

On the site I have buttons that say `onclick="purchase_digitalgood();"`.

***Do I have to change anything after November 20th or will my PHP/jwt/JavaScript code still work?***

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I found the tutorial again...

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial

it doesnt say anything about this will soon be depreceated, so all signs point to that I can still use it!

Makes me wonder: how come will Google process payments like that, but not process payments where there is simply a shipping address attached?

Answer (score 0):

- Google Payments has [different APIs](https://developers.google.com/commerce/).
- Only [Google Checkout is being retired in November 2013](https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449).

They are different products so in your answer/comment above

- Google Checkout was a checkout service, it was never a *credit card processing service*.
- Wallet for digital goods (**Digital Goods API**) is "similar" in that it's not a credit card processing service either. Google *handles credit card processing for you* . It's focus is on digital content (and therefore shipping addresses are irrelevant).
- **Instant Buy API**, the newest API, is a "purchase flow layer" on top of your **existing** credit card processing service.

  - Notice that this is very different from the former - in the previous services, Google handles credit card processing for you. You didn't/don't need your own bank merchant account. In this API, **you *do***.
  - this API is still **not** a *credit card processing service* per se. It's just a "layer" that allows you to leverage users with Google Wallet to make payments in an easier and more secure fashion  - re:  Google Wallet users store all their payment info with Google (only), they don't keep providing their payment info to multiple merchants every time they make online purchases.